# Monstera/Swiss cheese plant with brown spots on leaves?

Tags: plant-care, watering, tree-care, tropical, monstera

I bought a [*Monstera*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstera_deliciosa) about a week ago and the bigger leaves started to look floppy. I thought this was because I didn't water it enough, so I watered it more. I'm guessing this is where I went wrong because after that some brown spots have appeared on the new leaves and on the bigger ones.

The pot is about 3 feet from a window that gets morning light. The plant is in a clay pot that has a saucer and I removed the excess water from the saucer once I watered it.

If I did over water it, do I have to sit it out and see if the leaves will be okay, or is there something I can do to get the plant and leaves to look healthy?

Comment: Imogen, welcome! Pictures are worth 1000 words, so why don't you [edit] your post with some? While you wait for answers, take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about the site and the Stack Exchange system in general.

Comment: Monster is capable of guttation: http://plantsarethestrangestpeople.blogspot.ca/2008/05/guttation.html

If you're overwatering (which is likely), you might see the tips of the leaves dripping water or small water pools on the floor below.

Comment: It would be helpful to see pictures of your own plant, if you can add some,also showing the pot as well as the plant